# Getting some unexpected issues when analysis my GWT project with SonarQube

Tags: java, gwt, sonarqube, java-7

I have been developing an application using GWT and did a SonarQube implementation of it.
But it did throw some unexpected results :

```
    bDateStart.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {

        }});
```

Major Issue : "Rename this class"

- Can Someone help me with above mentioned one ?
- And is there a way to turn 'off' certain rules for my application ?
- Is this really a major issue as shown by SonarQube ?

Comment: Which version of SonarQube are you using ? Is the issue reported by the SonarSource java analyser or by PMD or Checkstyle ?

Comment: Version 5.1.1.   Issue comes up in sonarqube dashboard.  Analyzing using Sonar Runner 2.3 on windows-x86-64 system . Evaluation profile SonarWay

Comment: @Freddy-SonarSourceTeam Is there an update about this issue? I am using SonarQube 5.1.1 to analyze the source code of an Android app written in Java and I am getting the exact same issue **everywhere I use an anonymous class**. This is really annoying since the project is pretty big and now I have hundreds of this major issues all just saying "Rename this class". This is obviously a false positive or even a bug in SonarQube. Is there something that can be done to fix this?

Comment: I'm sorry but I really can't manage to figure out from where this issue is coming. Are you sure that you're only using the SonarSource Java plugin and not the PMD or Checkstyle plugins ? If this is the case, could you attach a screenshot of this issue as displayed in the SQ UI ? Is the issue message only "Rename this class" or "Rename this class to match ..." ? Thanks